# How can we deploy new SharePoint site definitions so that they are made aware to the SharePoint system?

Tags: sharepoint

How can we deploy new SharePoint site definitions so that they are made aware to the SharePoint system?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended deployment mechanism is solution packages (.wsp). The solution deployment mechanism automatically takes care of farms with multiple web front-ends, etc.

Answer (score 0):

follow the link provided below 
 
[Site Definition in SharePoint](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/sitedefinition01062009214413PM/sitedefinition.aspx)